# PMD showing errors for one class, but not another class with the same issue

Tags: apex, class, vs-code, code, pmd

I just installed PMD and its pretty janky from my experience, for example I have two classes and it shows the "same name" error for one class but completely ignores it for the other class....

has anyone experienced this with PMD or do you recommend
another tool for code analysis?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the PMD rule is case-sensitive, so the second class doesn't match, as there's a difference in case. This is actually a bug. I'll see if I can either patch it myself with a PR, or get someone who can.

Edit: This will require more research. The name comparison is [case insensitive](https://github.com/pmd/pmd/blob/master/pmd-apex/src/main/java/net/sourceforge/pmd/lang/apex/rule/errorprone/MethodWithSameNameAsEnclosingClassRule.java), so maybe something else is going on here. I'm going to try to reproduce this issue locally.

In the meantime, I do personally recommend Apex PMD. It's not only one of the best tools out there, it's practically the *only* tool out there that's specifically designed for Apex Code.